# Print only CEWP content

Tags: 2010, printing, cewp

How can I print only the content residing in Content Editor Web Part? The content inside my Content Editor Web Part is an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to print a particular `div` content

```
<div id="printDiv">
    <img src="image.png" />
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printDiv')" value="Print" />

function printDiv(divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

    window.print();

    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

Another way to do this by hiding unwanted elements from the UI using JavaScript and then `window.print()`